# How does React deal with pre-compiled HTML from PhantomJS?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, phantomjs

I compiled my reactjs using webpack and got a bundle file `bundles.js`. My `bundles.js` contains a component that make API calls to get the data.

I put this file in my html and pass the url to phantom.js to pre-compile static html for SEO reasons.

I am witnessing something strange here, the ajax calls for APIS are not getting fired at all.

For example, I have a component called Home which is called when I request for url `/home`. My Home component makes an ajax request to backend (django-rest) to get some data. Now when I call home page in phantomjs this api call is not getting fired.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I've seen some question about bad behavior of PhantomJS opening react.js-based sites. I would conclude that you should use the newest version of PhantomJS and if that doesn't solve the problem, you should stop programming and be a *... (insert flavor here) ... banker*.

Comment: should i try rendering templates from server then? Its really hampering SEO.

Comment: What do you see in your browser console when the AJAX call fires? Do you see anything in the Network tab?

Comment: Yes sir !! The ajax calls are shown in network tab and then return 200ok

Answer (score 0):

I have been using React based app rendering in Phantomjs since 2014. Make sure you use the latest Phantomjs version v2.x. The problems with Phantomjs occur because it uses older webkit engine, so if you have some CSS3 features used make sure they are prefixed correctly example flexbox layout.

From the JS side the PhantomJS does not support many newer APIs (example fetch etc.), to fix this add the polyfills and your fine. The most complicated thing is to track down errors, use the console.log and evaluate code inside the Phantomjs. There is also debugging mode which is actually quite difficult to use, but this could help you track down complex errors. I used webkit engine based browser Aurora to track down some of the issues.

For debugging the network traffic, try logging the requested and received events:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.onResourceRequested = function(request) {
  console.log('Request ' + JSON.stringify(request, undefined, 4));
};
page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {
  console.log('Receive ' + JSON.stringify(response, undefined, 4));
};
```